# PHP-failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: php, urlencode

I got failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in php.

```
<?php
$link = file_get_contents("http://www.abcdef.com/wl/api/allresults?state=".$location->state."&page=".$page);
$contents = json_decode($link);
?>
```

I got solution in google, if you are opening a URL with special characters, such as spaces you to encode the `urlencode()`.

I don't know how to implement this `urlencod`e in this above coding. Can u please help me?

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`urlencode()` is used like any other PHP function. Provide it the value you wish to encode, and it returns the encoded value.

```
$safeState = urlencode($location->state);
$safePage = urlencode($page);

$link = file_get_contents("http://www.abcdef.com/wl/api/allresults?state=".$safeState."&page=".$safePage);
$contents = json_decode($link);
```

See the [PHP Manual for more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)